# Задать позицию окна python

Tags: python-3.x

как задать позицию по координатам окна ,например игра Albion окно под названием Albion Online Client....т.е. мне надо например задать координаты верхнего левого угла окна игры 100х100 и что бы окно переместилось туда..
к примеру в АНК все просто было WinMove, Albion Online Client ,, 1, 1
а в питоне понять не могу

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from win32gui import FindWindow, MoveWindow, GetWindowRect


MoveWindow(window := FindWindow(None, 'Albion Online Client'), X, Y, GetWindowRect(window)[2], GetWindowRect(window)[3], True)
```

Замените Х и Y на ваши желаемые координаты.